# How Can I Re-Baseline an Azure Repo

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-devops

I'm a rank novice in Azure DevOps and I was using a local coding project in VS 2019/Team Explorer to learn about GitHub, Azure, version control, pipelines, PRs, etc.  I created a project, added files and, for quite a few months, I thought I was getting the hang of it.  A bit of overkill, but it was worth the learning experience.

Then a few days ago, after a month's hiatus, I returned to complete work on a local branch and nothing seemed to work correctly.  I can't recall what errors initially appeared (I attempted way too many "*solutions*" without really understanding what I was doing) but edit conflicts showed up, I couldn't sync, pushes didn't work, and nothing I could think of would allow me to resynchronize (not in the Team Explore sense) with the remote repo.  Edits I make in local files no longer show up as Changes in Team Explorer ("There are no unstaged changes..." despite my editing files, no "Commit" or "Stash" command is enabled).

How do I wipe the project's repo slate clean in Azure?  I just want to start over, learn from my mistakes and carry on fresh.

I would like to establish a new baseline, if you will, clear all the branches, commits, PRs, and the work items.  I would like to keep the Project settings, the Overview (Summary, Wiki, Dashboard) and possibly the pipelines.

Do I need to create a new project?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the issue in Visual Studio:

You could try to [re-connect the Project in visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/connect-to-projects?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2019#connect-from-visual-studio-or-team-explorer) and  clone the Azure Repo to a **new Path**.

[image: clone repo]

In this case, you can get the latest Azure Repo content again. Then you could make changes in local and push them to azure repo.

For the requirement: establish a new baseline

You don’t need to create a new project. You can directly create a new repo in the current project and push the files to the new repo.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Navigate to the old repo and select the branch that needs to be moved to the new repo. You could use the **“Download as Zip”** option to download all files to local machine.

[image: download files]

Step2: [Create a new Repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-new-repo?view=azure-devops#create-a-repo-using-the-web-portal) in the current project.

Step3: Unzip files on local machine. Connect to the new Repo in Visual Studio.

Then you can add all files as changes to [push to azure repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-vs-2017?view=azure-devops#publish-your-code-to-azure-repos).

The new repo will have no old branches, PRs and commits. But other parts will not be affected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks.  As you suggested, I successfully reconnected by cloning the repo from within VS2019.

It wanted to create it under a new directory (which differed by a single space from the old one) so I just let it do what it needed to.  Everything now works and I have a better appreciation for the PR process as described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzbkb0ve-XI).

As for the rebaselining, I needed to replace the remote repo with the files from the local repo.  I figured out how to do that successfully as well.